# UIScrollView: Nothing is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to get a UIScrollView working, but I'm having some difficulty. When I try to scroll, nothing on my screen moves at all.

There are no content size ambiguity warnings, which makes me believe I've set my content size correctly and the constraints are (I hope) fine (I have a view, which contains a scroll view, which contains one view that has 4 textfields and a textview).

I tried to programmatically set the content size to be really big using viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but that didn't help either.

I added in these methods:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("touch detected")
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrolling happened")
}
```

And when I run my app and try to manually scroll, "touch detected" gets printed once and "scrolling happened" prints many times. I'm so puzzled, as it seems like the correct methods ARE getting called, but I see no scrolling whatsoever.

In addition, I have this method:

```
func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo
    let kbSize = info![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize!.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

However, even when I click on a textfield that gets covered up by the keyboard, my screen doesn't scroll up.

I've tried implementing a lot of the solutions from searching on here, but it seems like nothing is helping. If someone has any ideas for what could be going wrong, I would hugely appreciate it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: you should really show the code for how you setup the scroll view and its contents

Comment: I did it all through the storyboard... I'm not really sure how to show that? Should I screenshot the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll views are a bit of an exceptional case with autolayout.  Make sure that you've got your constraints configured as described in [Technical Note TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

Also, if your delegate methods indicate that scrolling is taking place, but you don't see the content move, double-check that the content is actually a subview of the scroll view and not a subview of the scroll view's superview that is merely overlaying the scroll view.

Remember that UIKit should only be used on the main thread – odd behaviour with scroll views is one symptom of trying to use UIKit from a background thread.

Finally, use [the view debugger built into Xcode](https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-6-debug-view-hierarchy-storyboard/) to examine the view hierarchy at runtime.

Comment: As far as I can tell, my constraints are configured in that way, and my content is actually a subview.

How would I know if I'm using UIKit on a background thread? Also, I'm a little new to this, so can I have some further guidance on how to use the debugger to figure out what's wrong with this? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Got it!! It was actually something wrong with my constraints, the top piece of content in my content view was pinned to something outside of the scrollview, and it shouldn't have been. Thank you so much!!

Comment: If you don't know if you're using a background thread, then you almost certainly aren't.  You just click the view debugger button and look at your view like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUjbhGOV7DM).